# Best way to implement keywords for image upload gallery

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, keyword

I'm starting to spec out an image gallery type system similar to Facebook's.  Members of the site will be able to create image galleries and upload images for others to view.  Images will have keywords the the uploader can specify.

Here's the question, what's the best way to model this?  With image and keyword tables linked vi a HABTM relation?  Or a single image table with the keywords saved as comma delimited values in a text field in the image record? Then search them using a LIKE or FULL TEXT index function?

I want to be able to pull up all images containing a given keyword as well as generate a keyword cloud.

I'm leaning toward the HABTM setup but I wanted to see what everyone else though.  Thanks!!

Comment: I would go with the HABTM simply so that I could have a 'keywords' table, allowing me to do a "Suggested keywords" style feature. Plus being able to pull the most used keywords, etc

Comment: You might want to have a look at ZenPhoto, which is an open-source PHP image gallery with tagging.

But yeah, as others say, don't have multiple fields in one column, it'll be a problem in the future if it's not a problem now. Say you want to show your ten most popular tags -- that would be vastly easier and more efficient in HABTM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd highly suggest a HABTM relationship. IMHO, storing multiple fields in one column (e.g. comma delimited tags) is a terrible idea... Think of the nightmare you'll have in searching multiple tags, or if the keywords were input in the wrong order! Also, generating a keyword cloud would be nigh impossible if you don't have a keywords table.

So yea, I guess that's my 2 cents :D